# Gmail API doesn't provide full HTML email with styling like email template

Tags: php, email, gmail, html-email, gmail-api

Trying to get Gmail emails in our application using Gmail API. It returns email content, but it doesn't provide full HTML emails with styling like email template.

Following code we are using:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

$list = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',['maxResults' => 10]);

$messageList = $list->getMessages();

$messageId = $list[0]->getId();
$optParamsGet = [];
$optParamsGet['format'] = 'full'; // Display message in payload
$message = $service->users_messages->get('me',$messageId,$optParamsGet);
$messagePayload = $message->getPayload();
$headers = $message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
$parts = $message->getPayload()->getParts();

$body = $parts[1]['body'];
$rawData = $body->data;
$sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
$decodedMessage = base64_decode($rawData);

var_dump($decodedMessage);
```

This code returns only plain text/partial HTML email without styling and content image and full HTML tags. We need full HTML email code like email template. Can anybody help us?

Comment: Why do you think it should? Which actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Google doesn't see to have a PHP API library, which one are you using? Please add the link in the question. From what I can see you should be able to [get the HTML from the raw data](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message), but I cannot make the connection with the code in your question.

Comment: The API library link is : https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/tree/main/src